# NetSuite Suitelet add select field based on saved search or custom field

Tags: web-services, netsuite, suitescript, saved-searches

I know that I can use form.addField to add a select field with a list of records by adding it as a source in the addField method. I'm trying to show a list of customers that is filtered and only shows the name an not the id.

What are my other options for source in addField? Can I just enter the id of a saved search instead of a record?

What are my options for exposing the list of records to the user in a more controlled way, ie filtering, choosing the field the user sees in the drop down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately field filtering is not exposed via the SuiteScript `Field` API. If you want a filtered list of records, you'll have to do the search for those records yourself, then populate the select field yourself using `Field.addSelectOption()`.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you!

Comment: erictgrubaugh You are a great resource, btw. I look for your answers on these because I know you know what you're talking about.

Comment: Unfortunately putting a the ID of a Saved Search as the `source` does not work (tested in SuiteScript 1.)

Comment: the Field.addSelectOption() is correct. But I have to disagree with using the id of the saved search 

"Source list is a category containing standard lists and custom lists. Record types include standard record types like employee, sales order, and transaction, as well as custom record types."

Comment: Thanks; I removed that portion of the answer.